Debian 12 Calamares installation error
When I go to install Debian 12 from the Calamares welcome screen when I click on "release notes"  It pops up the error:

Failed to execute default Web Browser

this is from a clean installation so I would expect to see release notes before installing.
Can anyone tell me why this message appears?


Have you installed or set a default web browser yet? Did you choose a web browser package to install, or perhaps did you REMOVE the browser package when choosing your installation settings? Did you do any research on this prior to asking here? If so, what did you learn and what have you tried? Please add this information to the question itself.

This is a fresh install with no application choices made. To proceed with the installation of any component you must choose next.
